# How to remove something once drawn?

Tags: libgdx

I'm using libgdx and recreating pac-man, I'm currently using this code to spawn in the pellets for the level (essentially they spawn everywhere that the walls and Pac-Man aren't)

```
            for(int x = 1; x < 27; x++) {
                normalPellet.setX((x * 70) + 25);
                normalPellet.setY((y * 70) + 25);
                if(!(normalPellet.overlaps(walls)) {
                    batch.draw(pellet,normalPellet.x,normalPellet.y);
                    pelletCount++;
                }
            }
```

My problem is that I don't know how to make it so that when Pac-Man moves over the pellets they get "eaten" and are removed from the field. When Pac-Man moves over them, they do disappear, but as soon as Pac-Man moves to a different place on the map they immediately reappear. How do I make it so they go away permanently?

Answer (score 0):

Typically a game is redrawn on each render call (the render loop). Your game runs by calling your root `render()` method repeatedly. At the beginning of your render method, you clear the screen, and then draw everything again. So to remove something, you simply stop drawing it.

You need to create a List of all active pellets. This can be a list of some Pellet class that you create that has coordinates and any other state data that is relevant to your game (such as whether it's a "super-pellet"). Or it could just be a list of Vector2s if all your pellets are identical so the only thing you need to track is their position.

When a round starts, you should create all the pellets you need at the coordinates they should be at and add them all to the List.

Then, instead of doing your `for(int x = 1; x < 27; x++)` loop to draw them, you should loop through your list instead and draw each pellet based on its position (and possibly other data, for example if there are super pellets, you could choose how big to draw it based on that data).

When the character moves, you can check its overlap with each pellet in the list. When a pellet is overlapped, you can remove it from the list and update your score. When it is removed from the list, it will no longer be drawn in the other part of your code where you loop through the list to draw them.